# Install elasticsearch plugin behind proxy

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

After reading this [installing plugin using proxy](https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch/issues/152) I created command `bin/elasticsearch-plugin -Dhttps.proxyPort=xxxx -Dhttps.proxyHost=xxxx install --batch com.floragunn:search-guard-6:6.1.0-20.1`

but it is not working. How do I install plugin using proxy in Elasticsearch 6.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD 13 and Elasticsearch7 Tor proxy is an option.
To configure it install Tor and run it, then

```
setenv ES_JAVA_OPTS "-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=9050"
/usr/local/lib/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install plugin-name-here
```

Alternatively if you're using an HTTP proxy, change the first line to

```
setenv ES_JAVA_OPTS "-Dhttp.proxyHost=host_addr -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxy_port -Dhttps.proxyHost=host_addr -Dhttps.proxyPort=proxy_port"
```

where host_addr and proxy_port are addresses and ports for http and https proxies respectively.